# Converting UT (universal time) to JD (julian date) (astronomy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, astronomy

I'm trying to create a simple python code to convert UT to Julian dates, but my code keeps spitting out the wrong numbers and I'm not sure why, I can't see where I went wrong.

This is the formula I am trying to follow:
[UT to JD formula with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zSl8.jpg)

```
dates = ['4/01/2018 01:06', '4/01/2018 01:10', '4/01/2018 01:14', '4/09/2018 00:37', '4/09/2018 00:41', '4/09/2018 00:45', '4/22/2018 00:28', '4/22/2018 00:33', '4/22/2018 00:37', '4/24/2018 00:40', '4/24/2018 00:44', '4/24/2018 00:51', '4/24/2018 00:58']

JD = []

for item in dates:
    M = int(item[0])
    D = int(item[2:4])
    H = int(item[10:12])
    if M > 2: 
        m = M - 3
        y = int(item[5:9])
    else:
        y = int(item[5:9]) - 1
        m = M + 9

    JD += [ (1721103.5) + int((362.25) * y) + int(((30.06*m) + 0.5)) + D + (H/24) ]

print(JD)
```

Comment: You should show us the output you expect from that input.

Comment: But shouldn't that be `365.25 * y` and `30.6 * m`?

Comment: There are many good python libraries to parse dates. Perhaps start with `datetime`.

Comment: And as mvp says, you should use the existing library code to parse those dates. It's too easy to mess it up doing it by hand. Eg, your existing code doesn't handle 2 digit month numbers correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the function `Time` from Astropy Time and Dates package (`astropy.time`, https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time)

```
from astropy.time import Time 
JD=[]
for d in dates: 
    JD.append(Time(d[5:9]+'-'+d[0]+'-'+d[2:4]+' '+d[10:],format='iso',out_subfmt='date_hm').jd)
```

Note that I needed to set the function `Time()` with a format that `astropy` understand. In the example, I used `iso` as the major `format` which will expect something in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`, and therefore you need to also inform an `out_subfmt`, which I set as `date_hm` to specify that you don't have the seconds part of the time.  Once you define a `Time(...)`, you can change it to any time format you want using for example `Time(...).jd` for Julian date, or `Time(...).mjd` for Modified Julian Date.

```
print(JD)                                                                    
[2458209.5458333334, 2458209.548611111, 2458209.551388889, 2458217.5256944443, 2458217.5284722224, 2458217.53125, 2458230.519444444, 2458230.5229166667, 2458230.5256944443, 2458232.527777778, 2458232.5305555556, 2458232.535416667, 2458232.5402777777]
```